# Teradata SQL assistant connect to SQL Server, set preferences in using a libraries

Tags: sql-server, teradata, libraries, teradata-sql-assistant

I have one specific problem. In my Teradata SQL Assistant, I am connecting to SQL Server. But if it is possible, for me it will be best work with standard libraries in Teradata, like when I write help table, show table etc. the query is working. Right now it is necessary work with query defined in SQL Server. I think that must be possible somewhere set a preference of working queries. Or it is impossible?

Thank you a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Teradata and SQL Server have different query dialects.  HELP TABLE is specific to Teradata.  Perhaps you should use a different tool for working with SQL Server, like [Azure Data Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/developer-tools/data-studio/) or [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thank you very much. I hoped that exist some translator from one specific language to another... but it is maybe future... :D